# How to select the values of the value attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to hide a comment with its children by a toggling function, but I want to hide them based on the value attribute.

this is my js function:

```
function toggle(id, lft, rgt) {
    var kids = (rgt - lft - 1) / 2;
    if (kids >= 1) {
        var element = document.querySelectorAll("div.md#com" + id)[0].getAttribute('value');
        var low = Number(element.split('-')[0]);
        var high = Number(element.split('-')[1]);
        for(var i = low + 1; i <= high - 1; i += 1){
            var x = document.querySelectorAll("div.md#com" + i)[0]
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the result:

```
<div>
    <div id="com4" class="md" value="7-10">yellow 
        <a onclick="toggle(4, 7, 10)" href="javascript:void(0)">[-]</a>
    </div>
    <div id="com5" class="md" value="8-9">not collapsing</div> //because of the id but I want to toggle them based on the value attribute
    <div id="com8" class="md" value="10-11">collapses</div>
 </div>
```

but I want:

```
<div>
    <div id="com4" class="md" value="7-10">yellow 
        <a onclick="toggle(4, 7, 10)" href="javascript:void(0)">[-]</a>
    </div>
    <div id="com5" class="md" value="8-9">Should collapse</div>
    <div id="com8" class="md" value="10-11">Should not collapse</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: So you are using a // comment inside a html file ?

Comment: So, actually, nothing is happening? Do you get any errors in your developer console?

Comment: No you don't get any errors, but that element will be interpreted as a stray string and will be dispayed on the html page if I'm not wrong :?

Comment: Comments in html are done with  <!-- some comment -->

Comment: And instead of querySelectorAll() u can use getElementsByClass or getElementById as I see you are using id's on them

Comment: I suppose that you want to hide the `#com<n>` element based on the value attribute of the parent of the `<a>` element?

Comment: In the `for` loop you are trying to fetch the _com_ id for which it is non-existing, THUS it is throwing an error and stopping the execution of the script. in the for loop put a check like `if(x != undefined && x!=null)` before checking/setting the styles.

Comment: the comment I added it here just to explain the problem lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the behavior you want is that when the `<a>` element is clicked on, you want to hide the elements based on the numeric range provided in its parent's `value` attribute. E.g. in your example, you will want to hide `#com8` because it lies within the range of `7-10`, but not `#com5`.

To achieve that, there are some changes that I would strongly recommend doing:

- Give **all** your comments a more unique class, e.g. `.com`. I suspect that `.md` is a very generic class that you might use in other elements on the same page, so let's just get that over with.
- Do not use a reserved `value` attribute, since that is reserved for input-like elements. Use `data-*` attributes instead: for example, we can use `data-range="7-10"`. Even better, you can use `data-min` and `data-max`, so that we can avoid parsing the range. I'll leave the latter up to you.
- Do not use inline JS, but rely on `addEventListener` to bind click events to your `<a>` element

Now, to the solution: if we slightly tweak your logic, it is actually very doable:

1. When the `<a>` element is clicked on, get the `data-range` value of its closest parent. This can be done using [`.closest('div.com')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), and then use the [`dataset` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to retrieve the range.
2. Split the `data-range` attribute, and remember to convert it into a number by using the [unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())
3. Use [ES6 array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to assign `min` and `max` variables to the parsed `data-range`
4. Go through all `.com` elements:

   - If the element matches our trigger element's parent element, we ignore it
   - Otherwise, we check if its id—parsed using [`String.prototype.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to strip out the first 3 characters—lies inside or outside the numeric range
   - Then, use this boolean value to determine the `style.display` property of the element

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const collapseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.collapse');

Array.from(collapseButtons).forEach(collapseButton => {
  collapseButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // Use ES6 destructuring to assign min/max values
    const [min, max] = e.target.closest('div.com').dataset.range.split('-').map(v => +v);
    
    const comments = document.querySelectorAll('.com');
    Array.from(comments).forEach(comment => {

      // If the element matches the trigger element's parent, do nothing
      if (comment === e.target.closest('div.com')) {
        return;
      }
     
      // Otherwise, decide if we should hide or show it
      const id = +comment.id.substring(3);
      const shouldHide = id < min || id > max;
      comment.style.display = shouldHide ? 'none' : 'block';
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="com4" class="com md" data-range="7-10">yellow
    <a class="collapse" href="#">[-]</a>
  </div>
  <div id="com5" class="com md" data-range="8-9">Should collapse</div>
  <div id="com8" class="com md" data-range="10-11">Should not collapse</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead

```
<div class="box" name="box1"></div>
<div class="box" name="box2"></div>
<div class="box" name="box3"></div>

$('.box').on('click', function(){
    var value = $(this).attr('name');
  alert(value);
});
```

Or if you want to use value attribute

```
$('.box').on('click', function(){
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
  alert(value);
});
```